# Image_Graphviz Example shows nothing

Tags: php, pear, graphviz, image-graphviz

i´m trying to use [Image_Graphviz](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz) from pear.
I installed the package via pear install. All went fine, pear list displays the package as stable.
When I try to display the given example there´s just an empty page. Do I need to install more than the pear package?
I tryed with PHP 5.3.2 and PHP 5.2.7

Answer (score 0):

As the [manual page states](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php):

> Calling graphviz' dot or neato is being done by Image_GraphViz implicitly when calling image() or fetch().

So you need to install the graphviz program on your machine, and have it available in your path.